# How to turn a string into URL in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, url, ruby-on-rails-4

If I have a form input where someone puts 'facebook.com' or 'google.com' it turns it into a valid URL adding http:// so that rails can use it. What I want is to have a form where you input a URL and it grabs the 3 most used words at that site and shows them in a list on the results page. This list should be accessible later, so I also need to store those words with that URL

```
  def smart_add_url_protocol
   url = Url.find_by(params[:url])
   unless self.url[/\Ahttp:\/\//] || self.url[/\Ahttps:\/\//]
    self.url = "http://#{self.url}"
   end
  end
```

something like this.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What do you want to do? We also need to know what the final output should look like.

Comment: Please move that into your question, not in a comment. You want to put everything people will need to know to answer your question there, without any fluff. If you spread what they need to know across comments, then it takes a lot longer to get help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `URI::HTTP#build` like so:

```
URI::HTTP.build(host: 'facebook.com').to_s
#=> "http://facebook.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the [Addressable gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/addressable) which is somewhat smart about guessing URLs from strings:

```
require "addressable/uri"

Addressable::URI.heuristic_parse(some_string_with_an_url).to_s
```